# Wordpress installed as per the guidelines but website fails to come up even though Apache2 is running. All the word[press files are available in html

Tags: php, wordpress, web, ubuntu-20.04

I have WordPress folder installed to the following directory in Ubuntu 20.04 /var/www/html (all the files of the WordPress) however when I browse the machine with a Public IPv4 address I get the following -

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require __DIR__ . '/wp-blog-header.php';enter code here
```

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-124-163:/var/www/html$ ls
index.php        wp-blog-header.php    wp-includes        wp-settings.php
license.txt      wp-comments-post.php  wp-links-opml.php  wp-signup.php
readme.html      wp-config-sample.php  wp-load.php        wp-trackback.php
wp-activate.php  wp-content            wp-login.php       xmlrpc.php
wp-admin         wp-cron.php           wp-mail.php
ubuntu@ip-10-0-124-163:/var/www/html$
```

HOW TO RESOLVE THIS ISSUE?

Comment: is php installed and properly configured in that server?

Comment: You must set your apache configuration so it runs php when it sees .php files. As it is apache just delivers the php files to the browser.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.